# AWS - VPC and subnet group

Tags: subnet, amazon-vpc, amazon-rds

In order to create RDS, I need to create a VPC and two subnets attached to it.

If I choose 10.0.0.0/16 as IPv4 CIDR for VPC, can you please suggest IPv4 CIDR blocks for the two subnets that I have to create?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should split that up in to subnets with `/24`, like this:

```
10.0.1.0/24
10.0.2.0/24
```

Any `/24` in the `10.0.0.0` to `10.0.255.0` range is valid. I suggest reading the [VPC and Subnet Basics in the AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Subnets.html#vpc-subnet-basics) also.